# BLE scan doesn't find the device the second time I scan

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm implementing a BLE application and the first time my scan works fine. I find the device I do some write operation and I disconnect. Then the second time I try to find the device my scan doesn't return the device and I can't find the problem. Here's my code:

Scanning operation:

```
fun scanForBluetoothLamps(bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter, scanCallback: ScanCallback) {
    val uuid = ParcelUuid(convertIntegerToUUID(LIGHT_SERVICE))
    val filter = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(uuid).build()
    val settings = ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
            .setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE).build()

    bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listOf(filter), settings, scanCallback)
    Handler().postDelayed({
        bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback)
        _event.postValue(false)
    }, SCAN_TIME)
}
```

I call the operation the activity:

```
private val scanOperation = ScanOperation()

fun setupAdapter(){
scanButton.setOnClickListener{
 scanOperation.scanForBluetoothLamps(bluetoothAdapter, viewModel.scanCallback)
 }
}
```

And in ViewModel I have my scanCallback:

```
val scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
        result?.let {
            if (!btDevicesList.contains(result.device)) {
                btDevicesList.add(result.device)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
        results?.forEach { result ->
            if (!btDevicesList.contains(result.device)) {
                btDevicesList.add(result.device)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the disconnect function that I call before I disconnect the device

```
fun disconnect(gatt: BluetoothGatt?) {
    gatt?.run {
        disconnect()
        close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't clear btDevicesList between the two scans. Therefore the device is ignored the second time.